# Grunt Tests - 39mChrome have not captured in 200000 ms

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, gruntjs, karma-runner

I am trying to run Grunt Tests in the TFS build server. When I run Grunt tests using the Command Prompt manually, the tests get succeeded. However when I try running the Grunt tests from using the `invoke-process` step, the Grunt tests fail and I get the following error:

```
[4mRunning "karma:unit" (karma) task[24m
[32mINFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser Chrome
[33mWARN [launcher]: [39mChrome have not captured in 200000 ms, killing.
[32mINFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start Chrome again (1/2).
[33mWARN [launcher]: [39mChrome have not captured in 200000 ms, killing.
[32mINFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start Chrome again (2/2).
[33mWARN [launcher]: [39mChrome have not captured in 200000 ms, killing.
[31mERROR [launcher]: [39mChrome failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.
[33mWarning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.[39m
[31mAborted due to warnings.

Execution Time (2014-05-13 23:25:47 UTC)
karma:unit    600.7s  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 100%
Total 602.9s
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting an error here?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run the TFS Build service interactive mode to be able to get a UI started from it.